# Django rest framework CORS( Cross Origin Resource Sharing) is not working

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-cors-headers

I have done token authentication for the url **'localhost:8000/api/posts'** and according to django-cors-headers library I have also changed the settings.py file. Here is my settings.py file,

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'corsheaders',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken'
]
```

Here is my middleware settings,

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Here are my other settings,

```
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = False
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ["http://127.0.0.1:4000"]
```

Here I have given access only for **"http://127.0.0.1:4000"**

This is my client django project views file which is hosted on **"http://127.0.0.1:3000"**

```
import requests
from django.http import HttpResponse

def get_token():
    url =  "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/authentication/"
    response = requests.post(url, data={'username':'thomas','password':'thomas1234567890'})
    token=response.json()
    return token

token=get_token()
def get_details():
    url =  "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts/"
    header = {"Authorization": "Token {}".format(token['token'])}
    response = requests.get(url, headers = header)
    return response.text

def homepage(request):
    x= get_details()
    return HttpResponse(x)
```

Now even though I am requesting for the data from other domain which is not mentioned on django cors origin whitelist, I am able to fetch the data without any error, I am not able to restrict other domains for accessing the data. Can anyone please help me in solving this issue.

Comment: I think your issue is because of the position of middleware for cors try putting it after the session middleware

Comment: I have also tried that but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

use this setting for your app. This happened because of the fact that you are using `HTTPS` over `HTTP`.

`SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

According to [docs](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers#cors_allow_all_origins) for CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS

> If True, all origins will be allowed. **Other settings restricting
> allowed origins will be ignored.** Defaults to False.

So it looks like your CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS is ignored because CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS is explicitly set to False forbidding all origins.

Comment: This makes no sense. It defaults to `False`, setting it to `False` should do nothing.